# VHD does not automatically reattach on restart

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, vhd

I have some virtual hard disks mounted on my company's web server, but any time I have to reboot it to install Windows Updates, I have to manually reattach the VHDs. I'm guessing there's no built-in way to tell the OS to persist VHD attachments across reboots, so is there a command line interface I can use to create a batch script that will reattach them on reboot? Or what is the best solution to this issue?

Answer (score 1):

[diskpart](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300415) is the command-line interface for managing VHDs (along with many other facets of the Windows disk subsystem).

For your specific question, put these lines in a file:

```
select vdisk file=<full path to VHD>
attach vdisk
```

and then run it with `type <filename> | diskpart`.

That said, there may well be a way to persist these connections, but I don't know of one.

Answer (score 0):

maybe diskparts automount enable command.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the directions [here](https://www.mysysadmintips.com/windows/clients/408-automatically-attach-virtual-hard-disk-vhd-on-system-startup)

Basically you are creating a diskpart script and then linking the script to a scheduled task that runs on system startup.